# Execute cmd commands from windows kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I want to ask if there is any way to execute cmd commands (like we execute via `system(command)` in user mode in C++) in kernel mode?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. You can spawn user processes, but the commandline won't be processed in the same way the cmd woud be.

The best way is having a usermode process that communicates with the kernel (using minifilter communication or ioctl calls) and executes whatever is needed.

Comment: I got it, so can we connect to physical serial port (COM1) from our driver? I need suggestion (this is off topic),